# Cannot pass variable into while loop

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I've tried this a few ways but trying to pass a variable into this code when it's a text file just doesn't work.  What's weird though is if the check sees it's just a url, it works perfectly.

I've tried -i in wget, quotes around $line, {} around line, putting $directory a few ways into wget.  Nothing.  It either reads it as blank or as the file name, not the urls in the file.

On top of this mess, $savefile.log in the first part of the loop always returns directory.txt.log.  Tried $line.log to fix that and nada.  I do need it stripped as : and \ are not valid in a file name.

```
   #!/bin/bash

   read -p "Enter directory or .txt file: `echo $'\n> '`" directory

   savefile=$(echo "${directory//"http://"}" | cut -d '/' -f1)

   if [[ $directory == *.txt ]] 
    echo
    echo "Spidering $directory"
        while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
            echo "$line"
            wget -np --spider -e robots=off --no-check-certificate $line 2>> $savefile.log
            echo
            echo "Spider saved to $savefile.log"
        done < $directory
    else
        echo
        echo "Spidering $directory"
        wget -r -np --spider -e robots=off --no-check-certificate $directory 2>> $savefile.log
        echo
        echo "Spider saved to $savefile.log"
fi
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The command substitution isn't necessary; `$'...'` is not restricted to escape sequences. `read -p $'Enter directory or .txt file:\n> ' directory`.

Comment: Make sure your data files are proper text files (with a terminating newline), and you won't need the `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` hack to make the script work.

Answer (score 0):

EDITx2??:
Removing my old answer because it was wrong, finally got a chance to sit down and run the code, and based off what I THINK you were looking for this should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter directory or .txt file: `echo $'\n> '`" directory

if [[ $directory == *.txt ]]; then
    echo
    echo "Spidering $directory"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "$line"
        savefile="$(basename "${directory//.txt}")"
        wget -np --spider -e robots=off --no-check-certificate $line 2>> $savefile.log
        echo
        echo "Spider saved to $savefile.log"
    done < $directory
else
    echo
    echo "Spidering $directory"
    savefile=$(echo "${directory//"http://"}" | cut -d '/' -f1)
    wget -r -np --spider -e robots=off --no-check-certificate $directory 2>> $savefile.log
    echo
    echo "Spider saved to $savefile.log"
fi
```

One big issue was you forgot the `; then` at the end of the `if [[ ... ]]` line.

With savefile, I am guessing you were aiming to strip off extra after the ".com" on a url and give just the file name of a file? Works perfect for a url as written, but it nukes file path. Moved it into the else as written. For a file, `basename` removes the directories and just leaves the file name and the variable expansion strips the troublesome '.txt'.

Tried not to deviate from your code by much, but I would recommend quoting the variables - shouldn't be spaces in the URL, but ~could be~ if input wrong, but mainly because filenames could have un-escaped spaces.

Could also make a tad more compact by using `'echo -e "\nSpidering $directory"'` instead of the double echoes. Don't suppose anything wrong with them but they bug my ocd. :P

Finally, I would recommend using the newer syntax for the command substitution, `"$(echo "cmd")"` instead of the backticks. Again not technically wrong, but since the back-ticks are deprecated they may eventually stop working. Also, and more so I'd say, it makes the code allot more readable, I have to squint at times to tell if it is a single quote or a back-tick.

Comment: See, the cleaned function works, but only in the second section.  It has to be do with the way I'm passing variable into the loop.  I'm not even sure why $savefle isn't passing properly into it.

Comment: @eggdaddy Did the above work for you? If not, yet me know and I'll see what else we can come up with.